# how to DRY this code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, dry, helper

I have the following line of code in several of my models:

```
def average(scores)
  # get average of scores and round to two decimal places
  average = scores.inject{ |sum, el| sum + el }.to_f / scores.size
  average.round(2)
end
```

I've tried to put it in various helper files, with varying success - but the problem isn't that I can't getting working, it's that it takes some ugly code and/or extra files (modules, etc) just to include this method in all of models - and that's raising some red flags.  It shouldn't be that hard.

Helper code is easy for controllers and views, but seems really counter-intuitive for models - at the same time, it seems silly to have (literally) the exact same code in 4 places.  What's the best way to dry this out?

**update**

I want to use the `average` helper inside of each model's methods - which are different in every case, but for the last line where everything is averaged - like so:

```
def avg_for(student)
  scores = []
  self.evals.map do |student_id, evals|
    evals.select {student_id == student.id}.each do |eval|
      scores << eval.score
    end  
  end    
  average(scores) #here!
end
```

Comment: could you provide a little bit more code? helpers are just for views, not voor controllers + models.

Comment: What do you mean by `model methods`? `instance methods`?

Comment: oh, sorry that wasn't very clear - edited

Comment: @dax no sure I fully grasp your question but see my edit, I rewrote your `avg_for` method. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this very specific method, you can use @delba answer.

To answer exactly your question about sharing methods across models, that's a [concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) job.

In rails-4, concerns becomes top level citizen, and directories `app/models/concerns` and `app/controllers/concerns` are automatically created.

You can add something like that, in `app/concerns/averageable.rb` :

```
module Averageable
  def average(scores)
    # get average of scores and round to two decimal places
    average = scores.inject{ |sum, el| sum + el }.to_f / scores.size
    average.round(2)
  end
end
```

Then, use it in your model :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Averageable
end
```

The methods from your concern will be available for any model that includes it.

Edit :

To do the same in rails-3, add the path you want to put your concerns in into `config.autoload_paths`, in `config/application.rb` :

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/concerns)
```

And put the `averageable.rb` module in that directory.

Comment: You can do it in rails-3 too, you just have to put your module in some place where it can be autoloaded, like `lib/`. It strictly the same beside that.

Comment: Getting `uninitialized constant Goal::Averageable (NameError)` (it's in `Goal.rb`)

Comment: Did you restart your console / server / zeus process ?

Comment: Oh wait, `lib/` wasn't added to autoload_path neither, in rails-3. You have to add it (or any directory you prefer) in `config/application.rb`, the `config.autoload_paths` array (available commented by default)

Comment: great, that worked - i put `averageable.rb` directly in lib, so my application.rb addition looked like this: `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)`

Answer (score 2):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-average

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :evals

  def average_score
    evals.average(:score)
  end
end
```

Outside of Rails:

```
def average(score)
  (score.inject(:+).to_f / score.size).round(2)
end
```

**Edit**

With your `avg_for` method:

```
def avg_for(student)
  evals.where(student: student).average(:score)
end
```